# Center Nav menu using floating

Tags: css

Hi I tried to center the navigation menu by using floating CSS element but didn't work. Does anyone have any advices?

```
<header>
     <div id="top-banner">
   <img src="Images/headerlines.png" alt="lines">
   </div>
     <div id="logo">
   <img src="Images/logo.png" alt="logo">
     </div>
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="text.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="tables.html">Price</a></li>
    <li><a href="forms.html">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
   </header>
```

Css

```
.nav li{
    width:960px;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
}

.nav a {
display:block;
text-align:center;
width:320px; 
text-decoration:none; 
}
```

Sorry guys, this is my first time posting question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Where is the `css` code?

Comment: Show us what you've tried or it didn't happen!

Comment: Here was what I just tried:

#nav li{
 width:960px;
 list-style:none;
 float:left;
}

#nav a {
display:block;
text-align:center;
width:320px; 
text-decoration:none; 
}

Comment: so you want to center it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chriz123/ghx3avm4/1/)?

Comment: @HarryLe Please edit your original question with the CSS rather than adding it in as a comment. Makes things tidier and the question more readable. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :)

```css
.nav  {
   width: 960px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   list-style: none;   
   text-align: center;
 }
.nav li{
  display: inline-block;  
}
 .nav a {       
   text-decoration: none;
   margin: 0px 30px;
 }
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="top-banner">
    <img src="Images/headerlines.png" alt="lines">
  </div>
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="Images/logo.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="text.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="tables.html">Price</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="forms.html">Contact us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Glad that I could help :) Now you can accept the answer so the question can be closed :)

Comment: By the way, are there any other way to do this without using inline-block?

Comment: Change it to inline :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
margin-left:50%;
```

in the class "nav"

Comment: Don't think this would work. This aligns the left edge of `.nav` (not its center) to the middle of `<nav>`.